# How can I restrict the values of an XML attribute based on attribute values in other elements?

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd

I have XML elements like this:

```
<characteristic name="Length"... />
<characteristic name="Width"... />
<!-- etc. -->
```

Is it possible to restrict the value of another attribute to be one of the values of (XPath) "//characteristic/@name"?

So this would be allowed:

```
<widget>
    <characteristic name="Length">100</characteristic>
</widget>
```

But this would not be allowed:

```
<widget>
    <characteristic name="Bananas">33</characteristic>
</widget>
```

(Because "Bananas" is not one of the names characteristics.)

I assume this can be done using "key" and "keyref", but I'm not sure how to implement this when both the key and the ref are attribute values.

Also, how would I do this if the characteristics were listed in a different XML document to the widgets? (Is that even possible?) Ideally I'd like to use XSD 1.0, but I'd be interested to know if XSD 1.1 adds anything useful here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample schema:

```
<xs:schema
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="characteristics">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
              <xs:element name="characteristic">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="widgets">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
              <xs:element name="widget">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="characteristic">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent>
                          <xs:extension base="xs:integer">
                            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                          </xs:extension>
                        </xs:simpleContent>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:key name="cname">
      <xs:selector xpath="characteristics/characteristic"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@name"/>
    </xs:key>
    <xs:keyref name="cname-ref" refer="cname">
      <xs:selector xpath="widgets/widget/characteristic"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@name"/>
    </xs:keyref>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

When applied to the instance

```
<root>
  <characteristics>
    <characteristic name="Length"/>
    <characteristic name="Width"/>
  </characteristics>
  <widgets>
    <widget>
        <characteristic name="Length">100</characteristic>
    </widget>

    <widget>
        <characteristic name="Bananas">33</characteristic>
    </widget>
  </widgets>
</root>
```

Xerces reports the error you want: "test2014010301.xml:15:cvc-identity-constraint.4.3: Key 'cname-ref' with value 'Bananas' not found for identity constraint of element 'root'."

Comment: Excellent - thanks @Martin.
Can you also help with my second question, regarding how this works if the characteristics are in a separate document to the widgets? (For example, I might have a global characteristics document, but then multiple widgets documents referring to it - or is this not possible purely using XSD?)

Comment: I don't think the W3C XML schema language version 1.0 allows you to define a single schema to cover multiple instance documents with inclusion. If XInclude is supported by your XML parser then you could consider to use that feature to include your characteristics document in the widget documents and then the validating parser would validate the complete document composed by XInclude, I think.

Comment: But normally the schema validating parser takes a single input document to be validated against a set of schemas. I wonder whether your characteristic names are not static and could simply be defined in the schema (or a schema module).

Comment: Thanks again @Martin - they're not entirely static, so I'd prefer to define them in a document rather than as an enumeration in a schema. I'll look into XInclude; otherwise I'll probably just develop a software solution around the two documents.

Answer (score 1):

In XSD 1.0, you probably can't do this (but I'm not sure, because I'm not sure how the "controlled" characeteristics relate to the "controlling" characteristics: it might be possible with key/keyref as you suggest).

In XSD 1.1, it can be done using assertions or conditional type assignment.

XSD 1.1 is currently implemented in Saxon, Xerces, and Altova.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicions, @Michael - hopefully someone else can help with the implementation.